# Move certain change from one commit to the new one

Tags: git

Let's say, I've made some changes and committed them. Then I've committed several times more. Now I want to move the change of one certain string from that commit to the new one for cherry-pick. How can I do this?
The way might be:
1. Change this string to the state that was before that commit
2. Commit this
3. Than change this and commit again.
The last commit may be cherry-picked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your commit is NOT the last made on the branch**

1) Cherry-pick the entire commit from which you want only a part, with the `-n` option (to prevent it being actually committed on the branch and just import changes *from* that commit)

```
git cherry-pick -n abc123
```

2) Get rid of the parts you don't need, reverting them to the state before cherry-picking :

```
git checkout -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

3) Finish the operation with a simple commit

```
git commit -m "Cherry-picked abc123 (only took such and such part)"
```

---

**If your commit IS the last made on the branch**

Example tree :

```
A--B--C<<<master<<<HEAD
```

`C` is the commit you want to modify.

---

1) Go back to the point just before this commit with `git reset` (`--mixed` is default mode) to keep your changes in the working tree but off the index

```
git reset B
```

2) Add only the "not-to-be-cherry-picked" part and make a commit

```
git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2
git commit -m "some message here"
```

(as a sidenote here, if a file has both wanted *and* unwanted changes, you can selectively add chunks with `git add -p`, see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add---patch))

3) Then add the "to-be-cherry-picked" part and make another commit. (same as above, with the relevant parts added)

This will rewrite recent history of the branch, so if you've already pushed the commit you want to split, you'll have to agree with your coworkers on this operation beforehand, then push it with `--force` to the remote to replace its memory of the bad commit (so obviously, not if you're alone on the repo).

Comment: It's not the last commit. `reset` will work only in this case, right?

Comment: @SailorMoon Oh I see. Then it's different. I'll edit. Do you want to cherry-pick only part of a commit? If so, there are better ways than modifying the original commit (and all subsequent history)

Comment: I just want to move one changed line to a separate commit.